# iphone sqlite app startup issues

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have 4 database catalogues in my app, i will be switching the four catalogues.
When i start the app, i read the NSUserDefaults and try to load the default catalogue in the memory, but in the first time this doesnt happen. Instead i get null values returned first time just because the DB connection is not successful for some unknown reason, the debugger is unable to go there too.

But the app starts up the next time, the values are fetched successfully.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trying to fetch some necessary data from the user defaults, it might not be there the first time you run the app. You probably need to create a default set of defaults (heh) using:

`-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`

...before you query the user defaults for any value.

From [User Defaults Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html)

> The registration domain is a set of
>   application-provided defaults that are
>   used unless a user overrides them (the
>   “default defaults” or “factory
>   settings”). For example, the first
>   time you run Xcode, there isn’t an
>   IndexOnOpen value saved in your
>   defaults database. Consequently, Xcode
>   registers a default value for
>   IndexOnOpen in the
>   NSRegistrationDomain as a “catch all”
>   value. Xcode can thereafter assume
>   that an NSUserDefaults object always
>   has a value to return for the default,
>   simplifying the use of user defaults.
>
> You set NSRegistrationDomain defaults
>   programmatically with the method
>   registerDefaults:.

Comment: Thanks a lot TechZen, Its a good insight by you. Helped a lot